# Como tratar um campo no SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, query, join

Tenho duas tabelas no SQL uma de **EMPREGADO** e outra de **Dependente**s e preciso trazer o nome de todos os colaboradores, independentemente de terem ou não dependentes e para os que tiverem, preciso trazer o nome dos dependentes também. Para os que não tiverem, tenho que tratar o campo com a informação "não possui dependentes".
O problema que até o momento minha query está retornando cada nome de funcionário com todos os dependentes. Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço.

```
SELECT              EMP.NOME            AS  NOME_FUNCIONARIO,
                    DEP.NOME            AS  NOME_DEPENDENTE
FROM                TB_EMPREGADO        AS  EMP
FULL OUTER JOIN     TB_DEPENDENTE       AS  DEP
ON                  EMP.COD_DEPTO       =   COD_DEPTO
```

**Aqui a imagem das duas tabelas**

[image: Aqui a imagem das duas tabelas]

Comment: Como não creio que sua aplicação permita o cadastramento de dependentes que não estejam vinculados a um empregado um TB_EMPREGADO LEFT OUTER JOIN TB_DEPENDENTE seria mais indicado. Quanto à mensagem bastaria utilizar `COALESCE(DEP.NOME, 'Não poussui dependentes') AS  NOME_DEPENDENTE`.

Comment: Complementando, utilize as colunas CODFUN das tabelas na junção (left join no caso)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimente

```
SELECT EMP.NOME as NOME_FUNCIONARIO,
       coalesce (DEP.NOME, 'não possui dependente') as NOME_DEPENDENTE
  from TB_EMPREGADO as EMP
       left join TB_DEPENDENTE as DEP on EMP.CODFUN = DEP.CODFUN;
```

Caso queira que os nomes dos dependentes fiquem em uma única linha, pode utilizar a função STRING_AGG:

```
SELECT EMP.NOME as NOME_FUNCIONARIO,
       coalesce (string_agg (DEP.NOME, '; '), 'não possui dependente') as NOME_DEPENDENTE
  from TB_EMPREGADO as EMP
       left join TB_DEPENDENTE as DEP on EMP.CODFUN = DEP.CODFUN
  group by EMP.NOME;
```

A função [STRING_AGG](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) foi implementada na versão 2017 do SQL Server. Caso a versão do SQL Server em uso seja anterior, você encontra outras soluções em [Concatenação de várias linhas de uma mesma coluna](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2020/01/05/funcao-string_agg/).